# golang - get interface implementation instance from struct after dereferencing

Tags: go, struct, types, interface, dereference

Create a struct that implements an interface.
Encapsulate it into another struct.
Fetch the struct / dereference it.

1. Fetching gets pointer to the implementation of the interface.
2. Dereferencing the pointer results in another point to the interface.

Why wouldn't dereferencing the pointer to the implementation gives the implementation instance?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/net/http2"
)

func main() {
    transport := &http2.Transport{}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    tmp1 := client.Transport
    tmp2 := &client.Transport
    tmp3 := &tmp1

    fmt.Printf("%T\n%T\n%T\n", tmp1, tmp2, tmp3)

    //dialTLS := tmp1.DialTLS
}
```

This code outputs...

```
*http2.Transport
*http.RoundTripper
*http.RoundTripper
```

As well, trying to access a property of the `tmp1` (uncommenting `dialTLS := tmp1.DialTLS`) results in compile error...

```
tmp1.DialTLS undefined (type http.RoundTripper has no field or method DialTLS)
```

...even though `fmt.Printf("%+v", tmp1)` outputs...

```
&{DialTLS:<nil> TLSClientConfig:0xc8203ec8c0 ConnPool:<nil> DisableCompression:false MaxHeaderListSize:0 t1:<nil> connPoolOnce:{m:{state:0 sema:0} done:0} connPoolOrDef:<nil>}
```

What I am attempting to do is access `DialTLS` in the Transport instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a type mismatch here. If you look at the documentation, you'll see that the field `Transport` of the `Client` struct returns an interface `RoundTripper`:

```
type Client struct {
    // Transport specifies the mechanism by which individual
    // HTTP requests are made.
    // If nil, DefaultTransport is used.
    Transport RoundTripper

    // ...
}
```

So, the type of `tmp1` is `http.RoundTripper`, though the underlying type is `*http2.Transport` which implements the `RoundTripper` interface.

As for `tmp2` and `tmp3`, they are seen as pointers to a `RoundTripper` and not as `**http2.Transport`.

In order to retrieve the `DialTLS` field, you have to use type assertions to convert a `RoundTripper` back into a `Transport`:

```
dialTLS := client.Transport.(*http2.Transport).DialTLS
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to specify pointer to `http2.Transport` in my assertion! Many thanks!